# sql - filter a subset based on order of a column and group by

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking for a SQL query that given a table with data

```
+----------------+--------------+---+
|category        |id            |time|
+----------------+--------------+---+
|A               |abc|              1  |
|A               |abc|              1  |
|B               |abc|              3  |
|C               |abc|              4  |
|A               |xyz|              4  |
|B               |xyz|              5  |
|C               |xyz|              7  |
|C               |xyz|              7  |
+----------------+---------------+---+
```

will result in output

```
+----------------+---------------+---+
|category        |id             |cnt|
+----------------+---------------+---+
|A               |xyz|              1  |
|B               |xyz|              1  |
|C               |xyz|              2  |
+----------------+---------------+---+
```

I get up to this:

```sql
select category, id, count(*) as cnt
from table
group by category, id
```

Now, I need to know which `id` is more recent (greater) based on the `time` column, so I can filter only this subset. `time` column can only increase.

Is there better alternative than

```sql
select category, id, count(*) as cnt
from table
where id=(select id from table order by time desc limit 1)
group by category, id
```

?

Comment: no it looks just fine as it is, as you only wanat the last id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with data(category, id, time) as (
select * from values
    ('A', 'abc', 1),
    ('A', 'abc', 1),
    ('B', 'abc', 3),
    ('C', 'abc', 4),
    ('A', 'xyz', 4),
    ('B', 'xyz', 5),
    ('C', 'xyz', 7),
    ('C', 'xyz', 7)
)
select 
    category, 
    id, 
    count(*) as cnt 
from data
where id = (select id from data order by time desc limit 1)
group by 1,2;
```

works as you note:

| CATEGORY | ID | CNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | xyz | 1 |
| B | xyz | 1 |
| C | xyz | 2 |

another method is to convert that WHERE into a JOIN:

```
select 
    d.category, 
    d.id, 
    count(*) as cnt 
from data as d
join (
    select z.category, z.id 
    from data as z 
    qualify row_number() over (partition by z.category order by z.time desc) = 1
) as c
    on d.category = c.category and d.id = c.id
group by 1,2;
```

I would be inclined to test on your data, to see which works better for you